# meaning of complex php regular expression ~([0-9 /]+) (cup|tablespoon)s? ([-A-Z ]+)~i

Tags: php, regex

Can someone break this down for me? It's going into a `preg_match_all()` function.

`~([0-9 /]+) (cup|tablespoon)s? ([-A-Z ]+)~i`

Comment: Try this: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=~%28%5B0-9+%2F%5D%2B%29+%28cup%7Ctablespoon%29s%3F+%28%5B-A-Z+%5D%2B%29~i

Comment: Blue Ice, useful link, I'm saving it :p

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely from a recipe. The regex will match when the input:

- starts with any number, space, or slash, any number of times
- followed by "cup", "cups", "tablespoon", or "tablespoons"
- followed by any capital letter, dash, or space
- case insensitive

Works with:

```
3 cups water
1 tablespoon TOOTHPASTE
1/3 cups Apple Juice
1/3/5 6 cups ASDF-TEST TEST
```

Side note: You should [Google](http://regex101.com/r/tO9sY0) it next time.

Comment: First atom is any integer, space or `/`

Comment: Also the 's' after tablespoon or cup is optional.

Comment: @smathy Yup! Thanks, just noticed that. :)

Comment: The space is probably for things like: `1 1/2 cups`